# Synchronizing work performed by Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, cloud, azure-functions

I'm dealing with following problem:

My application analyses PDF documents whenever triggered. Each PDF document have multiple pages (usually 1-20 pages). I created following workflow:

1. When analysis is triggered, each invoice is split by pages
2. Each page is analyzer individually (OCR, some NLP, etc.), running Azure Logic app that connects multiple actions (SQL fetch, get file from Blob, Run Azure Function1, run AF2, ...)

So far so good, I parallelize the process so it is performed faster.

**What I don't understand is**, how to de-parallelize. Specifically, after all pages of an PDF document are analyzed, I need to run Azure function 3 which makes conclusion on findings from all its pages.

I am not sure if my understanding of how to work with azure functions is correct, but I look at it as kind of multithreading. What I'm asking is how to translate following (very)pseudo code to Azure cloud app:

```
list_of_tasks = []
for page in PDF_pages:
   # start analyzing page in scalable Azure function, writes results to database
   task = pageAnalyzer.start(page);
   list_of_tasks.append(task)

# wait until all tasks done
await Tasks.whenAllDone(list_of_tasks)
# get results of all tasks from DB and conclude analysis. 
finishDocumentAnalysis()
```

Thanks for all help :)

**Edit**

We're using Python as programming language due to some machine learning models we use.

Comment: Your description is each page trigger one function with logic app, however your code is analyzing  the whole pdf file in for loop. So what's your question point?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at durable functions, these are effectively a layer on top of standard functions that allow you to do exactly this kind of thing and they handle all the tricky parts of fanning out and back in.

Check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp) to get started.

This [overview document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) is also useful to understand how durable functions work and it talks about some other common use cases/patterns.

The [fan out/in pattern is described in the above overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#fan-in-out) with a nice diagram too as pointed out by @silent in the comments.

Comment: Agree, Durable Fuctions in the Fan-out/Fan-in pattern are the way to go here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#fan-in-out

Comment: @silent - have added that link to the answer, thanks. Nice picture on your website by the way! I used to live down by the Chiemsee, are you based in southern DE?

Comment: Cool, very nice :)